# No space bar function in jquery mobile in form a form in a listview

Tags: jquery, mobile

I have a form inside a listview in a jquery mobile web site. The form has five fields, four of them accept int numbers, and the last field must accept text introduced by the user. When I check the site in Firefox and Chrome, the user can insert text in the text field but white spaces (space bar) are not allowed, nothing happens when hitting the space bar.
Is it a jquery molibe bug? I have seen that the problem has been reported in some forums, but no answer for the moment.
Thank you in advance.

Yes...this part of the code:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="b" data-filter="true">

      <?php $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbexistencias WHERE restaurante = '".$_GET['id']."' ");
      while ($e =mysql_fetch_array($query)){?>

        <li><a href="#" rel="external">
          <h3><?php echo obtenernombreproducto($e['producto'])."<br> (".obtenerpresentacionind($e['producto']).")"?></h3>
          <p><?php echo obtenercategoriaproducto($e['producto'])?></p>
        <p><?php echo "Almacenado en<h3> ".obteneralmacen($e['almacen'])."</h3>"?>          </p>
<form id="ajax-form" class="autosubmit" method="post" action="addexistencia.php">
<fieldset>
<legend>Actualizar existencias</legend>
<p>
  <label> Existencias actuales:</label>
  <input name="existencias" value="<?php echo $e['existencias']?>"/>
</p>
<p>
  <label for="textousuario">Observaciones</label>
  <textarea name="textousuario" id="textousuario"></textarea>
  <input id="where" type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $e['id']?>" />
</p>
</fieldset>
</form>
        </a>

         </li>
        <?php }?>
      </ul>
```

The text that doesn't accept spaces is textousuario.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: This is part of the code: